# pdftoppm converts only one first page of pdf

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, xpdf, pdftoppm

I need to convert pdf to pgm, and when I run the (example)command

```
pdftoppm -f 5 -l 10 -gray input.pdf > output.pgm
```

I am getting the first page of the pdf as output. This is even though I am clearly specifying first page as page 5. I am **not** specifying -singlefile parameter, that could cause this. Even when I specify a single page, like

```
pdftoppm -f 5 -l 5 -gray input.pdf > output.pgm
```

, the first page is converted. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case use pdftoppm thusly:

```
pdftoppm -gray input.pdf your-output-prefix
```

it creates files `your-output-prefix-X.pgm` for every page number X.